# Button constraints result not as expected in simulator and older iphones

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i have a smile button inside an UIView and i am trying to add a + button on the top right side of the existing button. I added the constraints for leading and trailing as well as height and width for the + button. So if i run the app on the simulator using iphone 8 simulator i get + a bit off to the right of the smile button although i placed it in the xcode touching the smile button. Also if i use iphone 11 simulator i get a much smaller + button which is totally another strange behaviour! What am i missing? I have the same behaviour if i run the app on my iphone 8 device. Here is the picture from xcode with the constraints.

[image]

Here are the constraints of the smile button

[image]

Comment: It doesn't make sense to constrain the + to the leading/trailing of the superview since that is going to depend on the size of the superview. You should constrain the + relative to the center of the smile image.

Comment: @Paulw11 And if i center it to the smile image how i am gonna move it a bit to the right? I need another constraint for that?

Comment: Don't center it. Use an offset from the center. So create a center X constraint for the plus equal to the center x of the smile + 15 and the same for the center y (the +15 is a guess, you will need to play around to get the offset you want)

Comment: @Paulw11 Your idea got me to another idea. Just added a leading to the smile image instead of the superview and it worked. I guess both your idea and mine are right if i understand correctly...

Comment: No need for leading and trailing if you have width. You just have to set constraint of + center x,y to respectively trailing,top of smiley. Also keep the width and height.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you offset from the leading edge and top or the centre. All that changes is the offset amount. The point is you need the constraint to be relative to the smile image, not the superview.